# How to alias an annotated type?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want to create a type that enables me to associate a type with a positive number.

```py
type Array = # what I want to create

class MyIp:
    ip: Array[float, 4] # Define a array of 4 elements
```

Under the hood, I was planning to use `Annotated` to make this possible

```py
class MyIp:
    ip: Annotated[tuple[u8, ...], 4]
```

But I can't seem to create an `Array` type that would work.

```py
T = TypeVar("T")
type Array = Annotated[tuple[T, ...], int] # Does not work
```

The error message is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\test.py", line 7, in <module>
    class MyIp:
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\test.py", line 8, in MyIp
    ip: Array[int, 4]
        ~~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: Only generic type aliases are subscriptable
```

Do you have any idea how to create `Array` ?

Comment: What exactly does "Does not work" mean?

Comment: `type Array[T] = Annotated[tuple[T, ...], int]` should work fine. Whether any tool knows what it *means* is another matter. Annotated types don't have any defined semantics. They just preserve the type data originally given to them. (I.e., you can access the tuple type from `Array.__value__.__args__` and the `int` constraint from `Array.__value__.__metadata__`.

Comment: What you are trying to define is a *dependent type*, one in which the type depends on a *value*. This is something that, as far as I know, is not supported by `typing` at all, let alone by any particular type checker.

Comment: Sorry, I have eddited my post with the error messages

Comment: You could define a regular class `Array` with a custom `__class_getitem__` method to turn `Array[float, 4]` into `Annotated[tuple[float, ...], 4]`, but the problem remains that no existing type checker would know what that annotated type is supposed to *mean*.

Comment: That's interesting @chepner. Do you have an example of using __class_getitem__ for types? As for the "meaning" of Annotated, I understand mypy won't be able to understand the meaning of it. I'm focussing this question on how to create a nice "type API".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, as long as you are only using this for documentary purposes, you can define `Array` as a type with a custom `__class_getitem__` method to return the `Annotated` type you mention.

```
class Array:
    def __class_getitem__(cls, t):
        dtype, size = t
        return Annotated[dtype, size]


class MyIp:
    ip: Array[float, 4]
```

It's a fairly fragile abstraction. `Array[float, 4]` is immediately evaluated, so `MyIp.__annotations__` will refer to `Annotated[float, 4]`, not `Array[float, 4]`, and `typing.get_type_hints(MyIp)` will return `{'ip': <class 'float'>}`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit disappointed that the "Array" completely disappears, but `typing.Annotated[float, 4]` is already very good!

Comment: Considering the API I'm trying to craft, do you have a better idea? Maybe I'm simply not at the right place, right now.

Comment: Only to note that `Array.__class_getitem__` can return literally anything, but I'm not sure what else would accurately reflect what you want.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks a lot for your help. I just wish Python would add the `tuple[int * 4]` type syntax.

Comment: I mean, you can write `tuple[int, int, int, int]` right now; `tuple[int * 4]` would just be a convenient shorthand if `type.__mul__` were available. The only reason you got the error you did is that `type Array = ...` doesn't define a generic type, but `type Array[T] = ...` does. It wasn't the `float, 4` tuple argument to Array that was the problem, but inability to use `[]` with `Array` *at all*.